# How to force a three-way deadlock with race condition

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, locking, deadlock

### What I have so far

I am writing a test case for a deadlock detection algorithm. We want to detect *potential* deadlock scenarios. For the moment, we're checking for locks being acquired out-of-order.

A simple two-way test for this is as follows:

- Thread1 acquires Lock1
- Thread2 acquires Lock2
- Thread1 blocks trying to acquire Lock2
- Thread2 blocks trying to acquire Lock1 <-- DEADLOCK

We rightly detect this as a deadlock. But delay thread2 a bit, and it will not deadlock, but we rightly detect it as a *potential* deadlock:

- Thread1 acquires Lock1
- Thread1 acquires Lock2
- Thread1 releases both locks
- Thread2 acquires Lock2
- Thread2 acquires Lock1
- Execution continues as normal.

We detect this as a potential deadlock because Thread1 acquired these locks in a different order than Thread2. So if the timing is just right, a deadlock is possible.

### Where I'm stuck

I am writing test cases around deadlocks involving three or more threads. I can easily force a three-way deadlock like this:

- Thread1 acquires Lock1
- Thread2 acquires Lock2
- Thread3 acquires Lock3
- Thread3 blocks acquiring Lock2
- Thread2 blocks acquiring Lock1
- Thread1 blocks acquiring Lock3

Again, we can rightly detect this as a deadlock.

But how would I change this test case from a guaranteed deadlock to a potential deadlock? How would I change timings to continue execution as normal?

Comment: Wouldn't a naive solution be to just bruteforce every combination of interleaving, only keeping the order between operations on the same thread, give you at least one combination where your guaranteed-deadlock algorithm would get a hit? I mean, if you just let thread1 finish, then thread2 finish, then thread3 finish, you have a potential deadlock?

Comment: Acquire and release all locks in thread 1 and only then run thread 2 and 3.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen:  good idea; that's something I'm looking into. @AlexeyGuseynov ah of course, the perfect analogy to the first scenario. Feel free to make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to provide an example when deadlock does not occur with different locking order is to separate execution of all threads in time. You did that for two threads case: first thread acquires and releases all locks and only then the second thread starts. For three thread case situation is the same: you can fully run first thread, then second and then the third.

More complex scenarios are also possible:

- Thread1 acquires Lock1
- Thread3 acquires Lock3
- Thread1 blocks acquiring Lock3
- Thread3 acquires Lock2
- Thread2 blocks acquiring Lock2
- Thread3 finishes and releases Lock3 and Lock2
- Thread2 acquires Lock2
- Thread2 blocks acquiring Lock1
- Thread1 acquires Lock3 released by Thread3, finishes and releases Lock1 and Lock3
- Thread2 acquires Lock1, finishes and releases locks

But if you want a demonstration the simplest consecutive execution of threads is the most understandable one.